# html element to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, object

im just trying to add a style to the currency symbol. However, it looks weird when it is rendered on the page. And I want to change the style for one symbol only that looks weird.

Comment: How are you binding this to html? Please provide your html template file code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `$` sign in [`format()`](http://numeraljs.com/#format)**

```js
numeral.register('locale', 'btc', {
  delimiters: {
    thousands: ',',
    decimal: '.'
  },
  abbreviations: {
    thousand: 'k',
    million: 'm',
    billion: 'b',
    trillion: 't'
  },
  ordinal(number) {
    const b = number % 10;
    return (~~(number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
      (b === 1) ? 'st' :
      (b === 2) ? 'nd' :
      (b === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
  },
  currency: {
    symbol: '<span>฿</span>'
  }
});

numeral.locale('btc');

var number = numeral(1000);

console.log(number.format('$0,0.00'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

**But the recommended way of doing is [custom-formats](http://numeraljs.com/#custom-formats)**

```js
numeral.register('locale', 'btc', {
  delimiters: {
    thousands: ',',
    decimal: '.'
  },
  abbreviations: {
    thousand: 'k',
    million: 'm',
    billion: 'b',
    trillion: 't'
  },
  ordinal(number) {
    const b = number % 10;
    return (~~(number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
      (b === 1) ? 'st' :
      (b === 2) ? 'nd' :
      (b === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
  },
  currency: {
    symbol: '฿'
  }
});

numeral.register('format', 'btc', {
  regexps: {
    format: /(BTC)/,
    unformat: /(BTC)/
  },
  format: function(value, format, roundingFunction) {
    var space = numeral._.includes(format, ' BTC') ? ' ' : '',
      output;

    value = value * 100;

    // check for space before %
    format = format.replace(/\s?\BTC/, '');

    output = numeral._.numberToFormat(value, format, roundingFunction);

    return '<span>฿</span>' + output;
  },
  unformat: function(string) {
    return numeral._.stringToNumber(string) * 0.01;
  }
});

numeral.locale('btc');

var number = numeral(1000);

console.log(number.format('$0'))
console.log(number.format('BTC0'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```